# Path to Combinatorics Problem [$1.11$]

Tags: combinatorics

> **Problem**: Let n be a positive integer greater than four and let $P_1P_2P_3..P_n$ be a convex n-sided polygon. Zachary wants to draw $n-3$ diagonals that partition the region enclosed by the polygon into $n-2$ triangular regions and that may intersect only at vertices of the polygon. In addition, he wants each triangular region to have at least one side that is a side of the polygon. In how many different ways can Zachary do this?

**My attempt**: I began with the case $n=5.$ I observed that the number of ways in which $3$ triangular regions can be constructed is $5$. I then went on to consider a hexagon and observed that the number of ways to partition was $(6-1)*5.$ Furthermore, I deduced for $n$ sided polygons we must have $(n-1)(n-2)...5*5$ ways to partition the polygon. I would like to know whether this answer is correct and if not, then a proof or a sketch would be much appreciated.

Comment: The condition that he has at least one side of each triangle to be a side of the original polygon makes this a different problem than [this one](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/kooc/catalan/cat15tri.pdf) in case if someone confuses the two problems.  My initial instinct is to approach this recursively.  By picking the third vertex of the triangle using the edge $P_1P_2$ you split the polygon into two separate polygons with fewer sides.  I do not see this approach yielding an easy closed form, but is useful for calculating small values.

Comment: As an aside, the correct output for $n=5$ is $5$ and for $n=6$ is $12$

Comment: Your result for $n=5$ seems to be wrong. Can you lead me through your calculations.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi Just because it matches the first two does not at all imply it is the correct formula... please put more thought into it and try to justify your answers.  It definitely grows at a faster than exponential rate (*for $n$ sides, just the two cases $P_nP_1P_2$ and $P_1P_2P_3$ each have $f(n-1)$ arrangements, so it grows faster than $2^n$*).  If I'm not mistaken, the next term would be $38$.

Comment: @RithwikVidyarthi the link I included in my first comment has each triangulation *pictured* and one can easily see there are five of them satisfying the additional constraint that every triangle uses an edge of the original polygon.

Comment: Yeah. I made a mistake. I didn't know the answer. I guessed the formula first then cross checked the values.

Comment: As an aside, my initial thoughts were incorrect as running recursion wound up treating the newly created edge as a legal edge for the condition "at least one side that is a side of the polygon" causing me to overcount.  My initially proposed method would likely have worked for the linked problem however.  This does appear on oeis as [oeis.org/A045623](http://oeis.org/A045623).

Comment: Yeah. So for $n=7$ it must be 28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly different analysis confirming **marco2013**’s result. Any such triangulation must have two triangles, each of which has two edges in common with the $n$-gon; say that the vertices adjacent to these edges are $u$ and $v$, and call these the *poles* of the partition. Let $P$ be the path consisting of the vertices of the $n$-gon between $u$ and $v$ going clockwise from $u$ to $v$ and the edges of the $n$-gon between those vertices, and let $Q$ be the path consisting of the vertices between $u$ and $v$ going counterclockwise from $u$ to $v$ and the edges of the $n$-gon between them.

Every internal edge of the triangulation must join a vertex in $P$ with a vertex in $Q$, and the triangles are in a loose sense parallel: the line segment $\overline{uv}$ passes through each of them exactly once. Each of the triangles not containing $u$ or $v$ has exactly one edge in common with the $n$-gon; some of these edges are in $P$, and some are in $Q$. If we label each of the triangles not containing $u$ or $v$ with $p$ if it has an edge in $P$ and with $q$ if it has an edge in $Q$, traversing the line segment $\overline{uv}$ from $u$ to $v$ uniquely determines a sequence of $p$s and $q$s.

If there are $k$ edges of the $n$-gon in $P$, there are $n-4-k$ edges of it in $Q$, there are $\binom{n-4}k$ possible sequences, each corresponding to a unique partition with poles $u$ and $v$, and each partition with poles $u$ and $v$ corresponds to a unique one of these sequences. For a fixed choice of pole $u$ there are therefore

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-4}\binom{n-4}k=2^{n-4}$$

possible partitions. There are $n$ possible choices for $u$, and each partition has two poles, so there are

$$\frac{1}2n\cdot 2^{n-4}=n2^{n-5}$$

possible partitions of the desired type. (Note that the analysis is actually correct even for $n=4$.) The following rough sketch may be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I am reading this book and I was unable to correctly solve this question. I was getting the answer as $(n^2-9n+22) \cdot \frac n2$ which was clearly wrong. So I re-read your answer about 5 times and now I finally get and I feel so happy. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just one more thing, we could also phrase the ending as this right; as line $uv$ cuts each triangle only once, let $T_r$ be the $r^{th}$ triangle uv cuts. This can have an edge in P or Q (two choices). And $r$ is between $1$ and $n-4$. So $2^{n-4}$ choices here (and then add the $\frac n2$ factor)

Comment: @Aditya_math: You’re very welcome. Yes, once you realize that every possible sequence of $p$s and $q$s actually does correspond to an acceptable triangulation, you can make that simpler calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the number is $n \times 2^{n-5}$. I begin: I choose a vertice $P_i$ of the polygon (the number of ways is $n$). I draw a triangular region $P_iP_{i+1} P_{i-1}$. Then, I have two choices: draw $P_{i+1}P_{i+2}P_{i-1}$ or $P_{i-1}P_{i-2}P_{i+1}$,...

If I just draw $P_aP_bP_c$ (with $b>c$), I have two choices: $P_bP_{b+1}P_c$ or $P_cP_{c-1}P_b$.

Comment: Something feels slightly off about this explanation.  If you could go into more detail about why the exponent of two is $n-5$.  How many times do you have to make the choice between $P_bP_{b+1}P_c$ versus $P_cP_{c-1}P_b$?  From an initial glance, did we happen to double count and why, causing the exponent to decrease by an additional one.  Otherwise, I agree with this answer.  I just feel like those missing steps should be clarified.

Comment: I make $n-4$ times the choice between $P_bP_{b+1}P_c$ and $P_cP_{c-1}P_b$. And I divide by $2$ because I have counted twice each case.

Answer (score 2):

(Copied from a duplicate of this question, in case it gets deleted there.)

It has been proven above by Brian M. Scott  that there are $n\cdot2^{n-5}$ admissible triangulations. A  simpler proof goes as follows:

There are exactly two triangles $\triangle_1$, $\triangle_{n-2}$ having two sides on $\partial P$, and the remaining $n-4$  triangles form an ordered chain in between them. The structure of this chain can be encoded as an $\{L, R\}$-word of length $n-4$, supplemented with $\triangle_1$ and $\triangle_{n-2}$ at the ends, whereby $L$ (resp., $R$) means that the corresponding triangle has its $\partial P$-side   to the left (resp., to the right) of the "virtual backbone" connecting $\triangle_1$ with $\triangle_{n-2}$.

An example: When $n=9$ then such  a codeword could look like $\ \triangle_1\,RRLRL\>\triangle_7$.

Given such a codeword the corresponding chain of triangles can be embedded in $n$ ways into $P$. Since reversing the orientation of the "backbone" and at the same time interchanging $L$ and $R$ leads to equal triangulations we have to divide the obtained total $n\cdot 2^{n-4}$ by $2$ in order to get the correct number of triangulations.